# Split one column into two column using SED or AWK

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file .csv file that contain just one column of data and I would like to split the one column data into two columns.

I am some kind of familiar on how to use SED and AWK but I never used to split one column into two columns.

The .csv file contain one column made of 2 strings separated by an empty space.  I would like to keep one column with string#1 and create a second column that contain string #2

I am not sure about the code

This is what I have now:

```
One Column
String#1 String#1
String#2 String#2
```

This is what I would like to have:

```
Column One Column Two
String#1   String#2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With awk (and just stealing your headers):

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}NR==1{print "Column One","Column 2";next}{print $1,$2}' yourfile
```

This says:

1. Set the Output Field Separator `OFS` to a tab `\t` before processing the file.
2. If we are on the first row print out two columns with text `Column One` and `Column Two`
3. Skip to the next record with `next`
4. Print the first and second columns of any remaining rows.